# How can I get a public variable in PHPOO?

Tags: php

I'm trying to put a 'global' value in a PHP controller, because I use it constantly in different functions, so, I've to send it a lot of times in the view, I saw that I can do a public variable like an attribute in Java.
I have to declare the variable:

```
var $team="";// or public $team="";
```

How can I put, and get the value of the PHP attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class Example:**

```
class MyClass
{
    private $_a;
    public $b;

    public function __construct()
    {
      // example of constructor
    }

    public function set($a)
    {
       $this->_a = $a;
    }

    public function get()
    {
       return $this->_a;
    }
}
```

**Example of usage:**

```
// usage construct class and invoke private function set();
$myExampleClass = new MyClass();
$myExampleClass->set('something');

// set public
$myExampleClass->b = "i set a public var";
```

It probably best to design your class with getters and setters so keeping your variables private, unless you have specific reasons. Here is a good reference for [best practices and styleguide](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

I hope this helps.